# Mingw Disable Classes/Functions/Types Marked Deprecated?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

Currently i have a problem with the deprecated messages flooding my output and i want to stop it without disabling all deprecated messages. It is warning me about auto_ptr (which i don't even use in my own code). Even if it can't be done with a compiler flag, the std library looks like it could disable it, though i couldn't find out how:

```
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_DEPRECATED
  template<typename> class auto_ptr;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably selected the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` language dialect, or it's your GCC versions default setting.

[`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) is marked as deprecated with the current standard, in favor of the c++11 smart pointers from the [dynamic memory management library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

> *" (which i don't even use in my own code)."*

Are you sure that you don't even include any 3rd party (non standard) stuff, that might make use of `std::auto_ptr<>`?

> *"the std library looks like it could disable it, though i couldn't find out how"*

Just make sure that this flag (`_GLIBCXX_USE_DEPRECATED`) [is undefined](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), when compiling your code:

```
$ g++ -U_GLIBCXX_USE_DEPRECATED ...
```